# Android Java : issue with starting activity, error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set up a restore game method. I have a fragment_game.xml inside an activity_game.xml layout. I have an error: cannot find symbol variable fragment_game. Can anyone see what's going on with the information I've provided in the code below? **see updates below**

The AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.whatstate" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".GameActivity" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity_game.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context=".WhatStateActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/game_fragment"
        class="org.example.whatstate.GameActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

My fragment_game.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_high"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/menu_padding"
    tools:context=".WhatStateActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ResponseText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/response_hint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="8pt">
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idImageViewPic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="342dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.04"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#66FFFFFF"
        android:maxHeight="91dip"
        android:maxWidth="47dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/alabama" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/guess_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_button_margin"
        android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
        android:text="@string/continue_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The GameActivity.java code:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String KEY_RESTORE = "key_restore";
    public static final String PREF_RESTORE = "pref_restore";
    private GameFragment mGameFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        // Restore game here...
        mGameFragment = (GameFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_game);
        boolean restore = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(KEY_RESTORE, false);
        if (restore) {
            String gameData = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getString(PREF_RESTORE, null);
            if (gameData != null) {
                mGameFragment.putState(gameData);
            }
        }
        Log.d("UT3", "restore = " + restore);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**: My issue may be coming from somewhere else entirely. I've simplified my code, and have this run-time exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.whatstate/org.example.whatstate.GameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
```

This is my code:

```
package org.example.whatstate;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String KEY_RESTORE = "key_restore";
    public static final String PREF_RESTORE = "pref_restore";
    private GameFragment mGameFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    }
}
```

The same error occurs if I extend FragmentActivity.
The same error occurs when using this in the activity_game.xml instead :

```
android:name = "org.example.whatstate.MainFragment"
```

**UPDATE 2**
No more runtime exception after updating activity_game.xml this way, but the original issue of resolving symbol still occurs.

Updated activity_game.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    tools:context=".WhatStateActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/game_fragment"
        android:name ="org.example.whatstate.GameFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You should add activity_game.xml as well. I tested fragment_game.xml and that was fine.

Comment: I tested fragment_game.xml by itself, seems fine

Comment: please, post full `LogCat` report

Comment: in your fragment layout class is  class="org.example.whatstate.GameActivity" try change it to   class="org.example.whatstate.GameFragment"

Comment: @user2217535 that seems to do it!

Comment: @user2217535 but mGameFragment = (GameFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_game); still has an issue resolving symbol

Comment: the id of the fragment is declared as `android:id="@+id/game_fragment"` so you should be looking for R.id.game_fragment?

Comment: @NageshSusarla doh...yes.